Running Local LLMs in Production and handling multiple requests
I am trying to run a RAG with Gemma LLM locally it is running fine but the idea is I can't handle more than one request at a time.
Is there a way to handle concurrent requests with utilizing resources efficiently? Can cont batching help and how to write it in the code?
Used in the code:
llamaindex
Llamacpp
pinecone
flask

Try using vLLM instead of Llama.cpp (which is not thread-safe).
vLLM is able to handle in parallel  concurrent (overlapping) requests and keeps up with the most recent models (even ones released in the previous week, like Llama 3 and Mixtral 8x22B currently are).
